# How would I set the white point, black point and mid point using core image?

Tags: macos, core-image

I would like to set the levels of an image similar to how you can do in many image editing softwares. I would like to use Core Image to do so, however I am not sure which filters to use. Can anyone give me a pointer in the right direction?

Comment: I'm also looking for how best to achieve setting a black point in CoreImage.  It seems doable, since the photos.app in iOS is based on Core Image (AFAIK) and it allows setting the black point as of iOS 8

Answer (score 5):

After much digging around, I believe the black/mid/white point adjustment you (and I) were looking for is available in the [CIToneCurve Filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIToneCurve)

The tone curve filter documentation (like most of the Core Image filter docs) is fairly ambiguous.  e.g. the docs list the same description for each of the 5 input vectors,

> A CIVector object whose attribute type is CIAttributeTypeOffset.

After playing around with the values for this filter, here's the gist of how to use it for adjusting black/mid/white points.

For Black Point: raise the Y value of the 1st vector to raise the black point.  (e.g. 0.0, 0.0 will yield the default black point, 0.0, 0.1 will result in a 10% brighter black point)

For White Point: lower the Y value of the 5th vector to lower the black point. (e.g. 1.0, 1.0 will yield the default white point, 1.0, 0.9 will result in a 10% darker white point)

For mids, use the same methodology on the 2nd, 3rd and 4th vectors (at 25% 50% and 75% grey respectively).

Attached are two images.  The first is untouched, the second has the CIToneCurve Filter applied with vector 1 set to (0.0, 0.1) the other 4 vectors are at their default values.

This was the solution I was looking for, hopefully it helps you as well

[image: Tone Curve OFF]

[image: Tone Curve ON -- Vector 1 at (0.0, 0.1)]